# SQL. Суммирование нескольких столбцов, появляется NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

При суммировании нескольких столбцов появляется `NULL` в запросе SQL. 
Подскажите, плиз, как это поправить. `ISNULL` что-то не помогает.

Comment: Определитесь с метками, речь о postgresql или mysql все-таки?

Comment: Как нибудь подробнее опишите проблему, экстрасенсорные способности сегодня что то не очень, а без них не получается понять что с чем вы там суммируете и причем тут isnull

Comment: Спасибо! что-то не работает все равно( В общем, у меня есть данные по затратам пользователей, где по строкам пользователи, а в колонках месяца. Мне нужно сложить и по строкам и по колонкам, чтобы получить общую сумму. Я использую такой запрос: (SUM(CAST(Replace([Колонка 1], '$','') as FLOAT))+SUM(CAST(Replace([Колонка 2], '$',''), но при прибавлении третьей колонки выдается NULL. Данные в текстовом виде ($100.00), поэтому я их заменяю на числовой. В чем можеи быть проблема при подсчете всей суммы. Подскажите, плиз, правильный запрос –

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что вам нужно `IFNULL`:

MySQL Таблица:

```
+---+------+---+
| a | b    | c |
+---+------+---+
| 1 | NULL | 2 |
+---+------+---+
| 2 | 10   | 5 |
+---+------+---+
| 3 | NULL | 4 |
+---+------+---+
```

Запросы:

```
SELECT a + IFNULL(b,0) + c AS result
FROM table;

SELECT SUM(a + IFNULL(b,0) + c) AS result
FROM table;
```

Comment: Спасибо! что-то не работает все равно( 
В общем, у меня есть данные по затратам пользователей, где по строкам пользователи, а в колонках месяца. Мне нужно сложить и по строкам и по колонкам, чтобы получить общую сумму. 
Я использую такой запрос: (SUM(CAST(Replace([Колонка 1], '$','') as FLOAT))+SUM(CAST(Replace([Колонка 2], '$',''), но при прибавлении третьей колонки выдается NULL. Данные в текстовом виде ($100.00), поэтому я их заменяю на числовой. В чем можеи быть проблема при подсчете всей суммы. Подскажите, плиз, правильный запрос

Answer (score 0):

SUM должен игнорировать NULL значения при суммировании.

Например, если ты натравил SUM на колонку где значения 1,NULL,2 , то результатом должно быть 3.

Другое дело, если ты используешь условие, которое ничего не возвращает, то только в этом случае может быть NULL.

Comment: сначала проверяем на NULL, а потом остальные действия:
select sum(cast(replace(IFNULL([Колонка 1], '0'), '$', '') as FLOAT) + 
sum(cast(replace(IFNULL([Колонка 2], '0'), '$', '') as FLOAT) +
sum(cast(replace(IFNULL([Колонка 3], '0'), '$', '') as FLOAT)
from ...